# How to call save button function to get updated values and save data

Tags: syncfusion

I want to use **Syncfusion JS grid** in my **MVC4** project.

I am assigning **JSON data** source to grid with **editMode: "dialogTemplate.**

How to call save button function to get updated values and save data in my Database.
Solution with Example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below dataManager properties can be used to achieve CRUD operation in grid and send the edited record’s data to the server side where we can update database. And also configure the dataManager using UrlAdaptor. Please refer the code snippet.

```
[JAVASCRIPT]
var dataManager = ej.DataManager({
url: "Home/DataSource",
insertUrl:"Home/Insert",
updateUrl: "Home/Update",
removeUrl:"Home/Delete"
});
dataManager.adaptor = new ej.UrlAdaptor();
$("#Grid").ejGrid({
dataSource: dataManager,
…
});

[CONTROLLER]
public ActionResult Update(EditableOrder value)
{
OrderRepository.Update(value); 
var Data = OrderRepository.GetAllRecords();
return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public static void Update(EditableOrder order)
{

….
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();
…
command1.CommandText = @"UPDATE Orders SET EmployeeID = @employeeID, ShipCity = @shipCity WHERE OrderID=" + order.OrderID;

command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shipCity", order.ShipCity);

command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", order.EmployeeID);

command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();

}
```

I have created a sample based on this and the same can be downloaded from below link.
**Sample:** http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/EJGridSample585067088.zip